# Testing functions calls inside callback with jest - React-native -

Tags: javascript, react-native, asynchronous, jestjs

I'm testing the behavior of a function with a success api call, i managed to mock the fetch response, but the function inside `then` callback are not called, even if console.log showing the function is going inside the callback.

My test is failing here:

[image]

Here is the function im testing:

```js
tryUserLogin() {
    this.setState({loading: true});
    const randomPassword = Math.random()
      .toString(36)
      .slice(-8);
    const email = this.state.inputEmail;
    const name = this.state.inputName;
    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('email', email);
    formData.append('name', name);
    formData.append('password', randomPassword);
    const query = Util.urlForAddUser();
    fetch(query, {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        Accept: 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
      },
      body: formData,
    })
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(responseJson => {
        if (responseJson.code === 200) {
          firebase.analytics().logEvent('userSuccessfulLogIn', {
            userId: responseJson.response.id,
          });
          const userData = responseJson.response;
          console.log('userData',userData) // <==== i can see this in console
          this.storeUserData(userData, name);
          this.setState({loading: false});
          this.handleModalVisibility();
          this.props.handelAddComment();
          console.log('finish')
        } else {
          Alert.alert(
            this.props.t('common:title_error'),
            this.props.t('common:error'),
          );
          this.setState({loading: false});
        }
      })
      .catch(error => {
        firebase.crashlytics().log(
          `error tryUserLogin 
             LoginModal===>> ${error.message}`,
        );
        Alert.alert(
          this.props.t('common:title_error'),
          this.props.t('common:error'),
        );
        this.setState({loading: false});
      });
  }
```

And here is the test:

```js
it('testing tryUserLogin code 200 case', async () => {
    global.FormData = require('FormData');
    global.fetch = jest.fn();
    const userData = {
      code: 200,
      response: {
        id: 1,
        email: 'test+1234567890@t.com',
      },
    };
    const name = 'test';
    const email = 'test@t.com';
    const spyStoreUserData = jest.spyOn(instance, 'storeUserData');
    const spyHandelModalVisibility = jest.spyOn(
      instance,
      'handleModalVisibility',
    );
    fetch.mockImplementation(() => {
      return Promise.resolve({
        status: 200,
        json: () => {
          return Promise.resolve({
            ...userData,
          });
        },
      });
    });
    instance.setState({inputName: name});
    instance.setState({inputEmail: email});
    await instance.tryUserLogin();
    expect(spyStoreUserData).toBeCalledWith(userData.response, name);
    expect(fetch.mock.calls[0][0]).toBe('testQuery');
    expect(instance.state.loading).toBe(false);
    expect(spyHandelModalVisibility).toBeCalled();
    expect(mockHandelAddComment).toBeCalled();
  });
```